# Commutator estimates regarding pseudo-differential operators

Tags: harmonic-analysis

Forgive me if what I'm asking is too naive for Mathoverflow.

Given a compact Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ with Hodge Laplacian $\Delta$. Recall that the Riesz potential $(-\Delta)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ defined by
\begin{equation}
(-\Delta)^{-\frac{1}{2}} = \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-t\Delta}\frac{dt}{\sqrt{t}}
\end{equation}
is a pseudo-differential operator on $M$ of order one. I'm wondering whether there exists a commutator identity/estimates regarding the Riesz potential and the Riemannian gradient $\nabla$. In other words, let $r$ be an $(s,t)$-tensor, then what can we say about $[\nabla, (-\Delta)^{-\frac{1}{2}}]r$ in terms of the norm of an $(s+1,t)$-tensor? When commuting two full covariant derivatives, the commutator is usually controlled by the curvature term. But I'm not familiar with the pseudo-differential version of the story. Any insight or help would be appreciated.